# Offset to dropdown menu in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am using bootstrap to develop a responsive website. I have tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE where everything seems to be working, but the dropdown menu (in main menu) adds a offset to it self in Safari.

I checked the Safari inspector to see what went wrong, but the inspector seems to think that the dropdown menu is displayed correctly - even though it is not.

See http://birdatwork.com/stackoverflow/safari-bug.html for an example of what I am talking about.

The site can be seen at http://kik.vejnoe.orvad.net/en.
Hope you can help find out why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found out why it happens, but I have found a solution. The solution is that I wrote some JavaScript that listens for clicks on menues and window resize events (only in Safari). Whenever one of these events happens the code will position the menu to the left by using the jQuery offset function.